# How to merge 2 row in pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm dealing with non-numeric data in my workspace now.

I want to merge two rows in pandas Dataframe; I first parsed Series from df by df[col].apply(set) to get

```
original series = pd.Series([(a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i), ...])
```

And now i have to make

```
new series = pd.Series([(a,b,c,d,e,f), (d,e,f,g,h,i), (g,h,i,j,k,l), ...])
```

shape.

I used X[:-1]+X[1:] when it comes to numeric data,

but I have no idea at all now

because

1. index of original series is actually iso format string time -> numeric indexing won't be helpful
2. data format is 'set' -> cannot not use '+' operand

How could I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- "add" the original *Series* to the same *Series*, but shifted
  one place down (in case of tuples addition is actually a
  **concatenation**),
- take all elements of the result, but the last (`[:-1]`).

The code to do it is:

```
result = (orig_ser + orig_ser.shift(-1))[:-1]
```

(without an intermediate *DataFrame*).

For source data:

```
0    (a, b, c)
1    (d, e, f)
2    (g, h, i)
3    (k, l, m)
dtype: object
```

I got:

```
0    (a, b, c, d, e, f)
1    (d, e, f, g, h, i)
2    (g, h, i, k, l, m)
dtype: object
```

**If your *Series* contains *set* objects (instead of tuples)**

Let's create the test *Series* as:

```
orig_ser = pd.Series([ set(['a','b','c']), set(['d','e','f']),
    set(['g','h','i']), set(['k','l','m']) ],
    index=['2020-02-01 12:00', '2020-02-01 13:00', '2020-02-01 14:00', '2020-02-01 15:00'])
```

(with date strings as indices, as you wrote in the comment).

Then, to join them your way, with original indices, run:

```
result = pd.Series(orig_ser.values[:-1] | orig_ser.values[1:],
    index=orig_ser.index[:-1]).apply(sorted)
```

The result is:

```
2020-02-01 12:00    [a, b, c, d, e, f]
2020-02-01 13:00    [d, e, f, g, h, i]
2020-02-01 14:00    [g, h, i, k, l, m]
dtype: object
```

As you can see, due to application of *sorted* function I even got the
elements of each set in order, but now each element is a **list** not *set*.
If you don't want this feature, remove *.apply(sorted)* and then each
element of the result will be just **set**, withou any particular ordering.

Comment: Hi. I'm still suffering now because of Two reason : 1) My series's index is actually isoformat time string 2) my series data type is 'set' thus cannot '+' operand.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pd.DataFrame.shift()`:

```
se = pd.Series([('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','h','i')])
se = (se.shift()+se).drop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using +: `se[0:-1]+se[1:].reset_index(drop=True)`
- Using add: `se[0:-1].add(se[1:].reset_index(drop=True))`
- Using combine: `se[0:-1].combine(se[1:].reset_index(drop=True), lambda x, y: x+y)`

Answer (score 0):

Use concat() function for merge two Series

- **pd.concat([original_series, new_series])**